# Y-axis comming out like that

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf8cr.jpg)

The Y-axis is not sorted.

I wanted to create a graph showing amount raised every day, the X- axis represents date between 1-59 (feb-march) and Y axis represents funds raised on every single day.

dax= [10,20,30,40,50,60])
donax=  ['60,299', '48,610', '6,480', '12,286', '36,999', '25,600', '10,351', '10,000', '12,950', '13,000', '2,000', '17,501', '250', '1,100', '4,000', '2,000', '50,000']

#plt.yticks([0,1000,5000,10000,30000,50000,100000,200000])
set_figwidth
plt.plot(dax, donax)
plt.show()

Comment: Please paste your code as text (correctly formatted) instead of images. (Keep your output as an image though/)

Comment: The values in `donax` are all strings rather than numbers. Did you mean for that? Instead try `donax= [60299, 48610, 6480, 12286, 36,999, 25600, 10,351, 10000, 12950, 13000, 2000, 17501, 250, 1100, 4000, 2000, 50000]`. Note that also, the number of values in `dax` and `donax` should be the same, i.e., `dax` should contain 17 values to match in length with `donax`.